# Problem in the integration of the SDK with an application

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, mobilepush-ios

We need to solve a problem with the the intregration of the SDK with the Android application.

This is a scenario:

we're collaborating with a a development company in order to integrate Marketing Cloud's SDK in an app of a common client, but they've identified a problem with its implementation: - They noticed that many users experienced crashes within the app (on Android devices, version 8 and above), and due to their analysis, those crashes rely on Marketing Cloud's SDK library.

They're not able to identify the precise method which causes crashes because the problem comes up only in production, and they're not able to reproduce it in the development version.

They told us that there are not other SDKs or stacks that can interfere with the initialization of MC's SDK, and they ensure us that the implementation has been done correctly, so according to their analysis the problem is solvable only by you. Also, it seems that crashes come just after the MArketing Cloud's SDK initialization.
Here I paste the error stacktraces:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground() at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done 
+ 353(AsyncTask.java:353) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion 
+ 383(FutureTask.java:383) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException 
+ 252(FutureTask.java:252) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run 
+ 271(FutureTask.java:271) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker 
+ 1162(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run 
+ 636(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) at java.lang.Thread.run 
+ 764(Thread.java:764) Caused by java.lang.SecurityException: Caller no longer running, last stopped +863ms because: timed out while starting at android.os.Parcel.readException 
+ 2013(Parcel.java:2013) at android.os.Parcel.readException 
+ 1959(Parcel.java:1959) at android.app.job.IJobCallback$Stub$Proxy.dequeueWork 
+ 191(IJobCallback.java:191) at android.app.job.JobParameters.dequeueWork 
+ 208(JobParameters.java:208) at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.e$f.b 
+ 12(e.java:12) at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.e.d 
+ 4(e.java:4) at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.e$a.a 
+ 18(e.java:18) at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.e$a.doInBackground 
+ 2(e.java:2) at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call 
+ 333(AsyncTask.java:333) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run 
+ 266(FutureTask.java:266) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker 
+ 1162(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run 
+ 636(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) at java.lang.Thread.run 
+ 764(Thread.java:764)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see Google's LONG STANDING bugs with regards to JobIntentService and "star" this bug (ref. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63622293) and the other similar associated bugs.  This bug is *not* being generated by the Marketing Cloud SDK.

Comment: Hi Bill, thank you for the answer.
We are interested to know: if this problem has already happened to other users? If so, how did you solve the problem?
Do you have any advice to give us about it?